# PDO: не работает вставка во временную таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, temporary-table

Добрый день.
Сейчас активно перевожу сайт на использование PDO. 
Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании временных таблиц. Есть запрос вида:

```
$cr_sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ads_acc_temp (id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, ad_id INT, ad_photo varchar(100), ad_parse_date datetime, ad_city varchar(50), ad_district varchar(100), ad_type varchar(50), ad_price int, ad_name varchar(100), ad_size varchar(100), ad_comments varchar(500));";
```

И есть запрос на вставку данных:

```
$ins_sql1 = "INSERT INTO ads_acc_temp SELECT null, ad_id, ad_photo, ad_parse_date, ad_city, ad_district, ad_category_2, ad_price, ad_name, $tyre_concat, ad_comments FROM tbl_ads_tyres $where $where_tyres ;";
```

Судя по всему, данные не вставляются, т.к. lastInsertId() возвращает 0. 
Вывод errorInfo():

```
array (size=3)
0 => string '00000' (length=5)
1 => null
2 => null
```

Соответственно и Select по этой таблице ничего не возвращает.
Полный листинг:

```
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset=$charset";
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $cr_sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ads_acc_temp (id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, ad_id INT, ad_photo varchar(100), ad_parse_date datetime, ad_city varchar(50), ad_district varchar(100), ad_type varchar(50), ad_price int, ad_name varchar(100), ad_size varchar(100), ad_comments varchar(500));";
    $ins_sql1 = "INSERT INTO ads_acc_temp SELECT null, ad_id, ad_photo, ad_parse_date, ad_city, ad_district, ad_category_2, ad_price, ad_name, $tyre_concat, ad_comments FROM tbl_ads_tyres $where $where_tyres ;";

    $pdo->exec($cr_sql);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($ins_sql1);
    foreach($fields_tyres as $key => $value)
    {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    echo $stmt->queryString;
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
    echo "Last id = ".$pdo->lastInsertId();


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adsacctemp";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($row);
```

Comment: select null это нормально. Допустимое поведение, вернёт null и null допустимо передавать в AUTO_INCREMENT. А сам этот селект что-нибудь возвращает? Может и писать нечего?

Comment: @Мелкий Запускал запросы в mysql, все вставляется и селектится.

Comment: параметры у вас именованные или вопросами? http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php если вопросы нумерация начинается с индекса 1, а не 0.

Comment: @Jean-Claude именованные.

Comment: гляньте еще $dbh->errorInfo() http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: последний селект у вас лажа `FROM adsacctemp`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Когда подготавливал блок с условиями заключал параметры в ''. Т.е. что-то типа:

```
WHERE param = ':param'
```

Как оказалось, этого делать нельзя и правильно должно быть:

```
WHERE param = :param
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!